# How to import files from other folders in python

Tags: python, import, directory, init, modulenotfounderror

I have a folder called project that contains the folder dataprocessing and the folder SVM. In my classifier.py file, which is in SVM, I want to import a function and an array from two files from dataprocessing. I have written the following in my classifier file:

```
from dataprocessing.sortdata import sorted_simulations
from dataprocessing.make_train_test import split
```

In VScode when I write my code in the file, the import works, but when I run the file I get a modulenotfounderror, which says that "dataprocessing" is not found. I tried putting an **init**.py in both of the folders, but I still have the same problem. Do anybody have an idea of how I can solve it?

Comment: where are you running your file from? Which command are you using? It's important to define the relative imports considering that information

Comment: what do you mean when you say from vscode it works but when you run it doesn't ? Do you mean running from the integrated term of vscode ?

Comment: When I write from dataprocessing.sortdata import sorted_simulations, I don't get any problems like I would if it did not work when i use sorted_simulations, but when i run the classifier.py file i get the error. So I mean it works in the way that I don't get any warnings in the problems, but when running it doesn't recognize dataprocessing as a module

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your current working directory is in SVM where your classifier.py exists. Then, you are trying to import functions from files that are in dataprocessing folder & outside the svm folder.
So try adding path using **sys** module

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/dataprocessing')
```

after adding path you can write as below

```
from sortdata import sorted_simulations
from make_train_test import split
```

Comment: I still get the same errror even after doing this..